# Extending the GIF image without loosing its dynamic property

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image called Progressbar.gif,its an dynamic image(its an progress bar which is moving in forward direction). The size of the image is 489 px(width) and I want to increase the width of the image without losing its dynamic property i.e. i dont want to convert the image into static one.So if anyone can suggest me any links from where I can learn or if any one can put his/her learning experience then he/she is mostly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a "full length" animated progress bar image to show progress as it happens. A good way to accomplish this is to apply "overflow-x:hidden" on a surrounding div and then manipulate the width of that element dynamically. The CSS "overflow-x" property controls whether scroll bars are shown when the full content of an element cannot be shown. It defaults to 'visible', which always shows the obscured content.

Since content will not flow around the progress bar as expected, you will probably want to wrap it in a "container" element which has a width equivalent to 100% of the image's width. This unfortunately would have to be set manually.

Here is a sample jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/K8sFM/1/

The HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="mask">
        <img src="http://www.edufunstore.com/img/progressBar.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.mask {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.container {
    width: 257px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

And some sample Javascript to make it move and demonstrate how to manipulate the div.mask element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var progress = 0;
    var timer;
    var initialWidth = $('div.container').width();

    $('div.mask').css('width', '0px');

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (progress >= 1) {
             clearInterval(timer);   
        }

        progress += 0.1;
        $('div.mask').css('width', progress*initialWidth+'px');

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.....i thing u told me I already tried this. My question was actually the size of the container div was 610px and the the size of progress.gif image is 489 px. And I am increasing the progress.gif image according to the data filled by the user. BUt In this case after when progressbar.gif is fully shown(100%)...still some space left in the div because div size is greater than progress.gif. So Is there any way I can increase the image width size from 489 px to 610 px without loosing its gif property..

Comment: Naturally you could stretch the image with the obvious side effects. You could do something crazier involving CSS border images, but it would be difficult to make the animations line up because your progress bar image would be rendered multiple times to achieve the effect. It's better to just match your width to the image you have though.